# Fastest way on Windows to copy 38GB of files to 50 USB drives

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, dd, ramdisk

If I were doing this, on linux or Mac, I would

- make an NTFS RAM drive
- mount it
- copy the 38GB folder hierarchy to it
- save the RAM drive to disk
- insert a USB drive
- determine the name of the raw device of the USB drive, e.g., /dev/blah
- Use dd to copy the NTFS RAM disk file to /dev/blah

How would one do this on Windows?

Asking for a scholarly friend.

Comment: That really does not sound like the best way, even for Linux. For Windows, I'd use a tool specialized in copying that also is really fast. I've got great results with TeraCopy and FreeFileSync if you make a donation and set the amount of simultaneous transfers to 20 or more depending on your sync scenario.

Comment: FastCopy is the fastest copier I know. Even with disk-to-disk copy it achieves maximal USB speed.

Comment: He is copying from a hard drive, and the source material has lots of small text files, so I assume a file-by-file copy would be limited by source disk seek time, no matter how clever the copying app is, no?

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows built-in [RoboCopy utility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is likely about as quick as possible. You can try [using buffered disk I/O](https://superuser.com/questions/1114311/are-there-any-pros-cons-to-the-j-robocopy-option-unbuffered-copying), which might (or might not) increase speed further for small files.

If all the drives are identical, it would be even faster to use a third-party tool to image *one* of the USB drives and then apply that image to all the other drives. These tools use *direct disk I/O*, without need to create a file structure and then to populate it, so the limiting factor is disk I/O speed, i.e., that of the USB drive and the HDD. On an old external HDD drive, using Macrium Reflect, I commonly see speeds of 80 to 100 MBytes/sec. Some free (for non-commercial purposes) disk imaging tools are [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html) and [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). These are even more worthwhile tools in a commercial setting, and the cost is nominal considering losses of PC's that are not backed up.

Answer (score 1):

The image method seems very sensible to me. It bypasses everything slow from NTFS data structures to virus scanners. It is also feasible on Windows.

There are quite a lot of RAM drive tools available, like *ImDisk*, it’s apparent successor *Arsenal Image Mounter* (never tried it) and *OSFMount*. You can use them to create an image. You can also use Windows’ native VHD image facilities to create an image, but then you must use a writing tool that understands it. They are available in Disk Management’s “Action” menu.

You can then use tools like *Win32DiskImager* or just *Rufus* to write the image to a USB flash drive or whatever. Rufus appears to also support VHD files.